# Can't seem to get the correct output from my code block

Tags: c++

I was just wondering if anyone noticed i was doing something wrong with my code block. Ths program is supposed to be a test program that compares 2 dates. The function that im working on is supposed to return a 1 if the invoking date is greater, a -1 f the invoking date is less than, and a 0 if the invoking date is equal to the date in the parameter. My test Program :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "date.h"

using namespace std;

//date is initialized in a month/day/year format.

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string* d;

    date d1(4,1,4);
    date d4(4,4,4);

    int greaterTest = d4.compareTo(d1);
    int lessTest = d1.compareTo(d4);


    cout << greaterTest << endl;               //i believe these two lines are printing out a
    cout << lessTest << endl;                  //location in memory
    cout<<&d <<endl;


    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The huge compareTo() function :

```
    int date::compareTo (date another_date)
{

    if (this->year == another_date.year && this->month == month && this->day < another_date.day)    //if both year and month are the same, test to see if day is less
    {

        return -1;
    }

    else if (this->year == another_date.year && this->month == month && this->day > another_date.day)   //if both year and month are the same, test to see if day is greater
    {

        return 1;
    }


    else if (this->year == another_date.year && this->month > month)                            //if the years are the same, test to see if the invoking month is greater
    {

        return 1;
    }

    else if (this->year == another_date.year && this->month < month)                            //if the years are the same, test to see if the invoking month is less
    {

        return -1;
    }


    else if (this->year > another_date.year)                                                    //test to see if the invoking year is greater
    {

        return 1;
    }

    else if (this->year < another_date.year)                                                    //test to see if the invoking year is less
    {

        return -1;
    }

    else if(this-> year == another_date.year && this-> month == another_date.month                  //test if the dates are exactly the same
        && this-> day == another_date.day)
    {

        return 0;
    } 


    //else{ return 15;}                                                                             //if none are true, return 15


}
```

the only problem im getting is when i try to change the day (the second parameter for date).

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some dates that don't compare correctly?

Comment: Why you do not use another_date.month in some if condition? Error in coping on StackOverflow?Otherwise it is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, since I can't test it... But, your `compareTo` function has this line:

```
this->month == month
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
this->month == another_date.month
```

?

Comment: wow thanks, you right. I don't know how i missed it. Worked after fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first if statement and a few below it as well you have:

```
 this->month == month
```

This is comparing month to itself, I think you meant:

```
 this->month == another_date.month
```

Also you don't need to use the 'this' pointer all the time,

```
month == another_date.month
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

That might benefit from some early exit:

```
int date::compareTo (date another_date)
{
    if (year > another_date.year) {
       //the invoking year is greater
       return 1;
    }

    if (year < another_date.year) {
       //the invoking year is less
       return -1;
    }

    // if we reached here, the years are the same.  Don't need to compare them for the other cases

    if (month > another_date.month) {
       return 1;
    }

    if (month < another_date.month) {
       return -1;
    }

    // if we reached here, the year and month are the same

    if (day > another_date.day) {
       return 1;
    }

    if (day < another_date.day) {
       return -1;
    }

    // if we reached here, the year and month and day are the same
    return 0;
}
```

Along the way, the cut+paste error just... disappeared, because that test became redundant.

Comment: Thanks, this is much shorter than the way i was doing it an makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find your bug in your original code because it was too hard for me to read. I suppose that's why you didn't find it either.

This alternative might be easier to read, and easier to prove correct:

```
// untested
int date::compareTo (date another_date)
{

    if (year < another_date.year) return -1;
    if (year > another_date.year) return 1;
    if (month < another_date.month) return -1;
    if (month > another_date.month) return 1;
    if (day < another_date.day) return -1;
    if (day > another_date.day) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i realize my code is messed up and saw the error after somone pointed it out. I was thinking there was a shorter way but couldnt think hard enough to find an answer. I like the second block of code you posted alot more.

Comment: The second block is totally wrong.  It says that "Jan 1st, 2012" compares equal to "Feb 1st, 2011".

Comment: Yes, @BenVoigt. Thanks! I've deleted the buggy version.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're really set on doing an element-by-element comparison, I'd put each set of inputs into a `struct tm`, then use `mktime` to convert those to a `time_t`, and the compare the two `time_t`s directly. In a typical case, those will be a 32- or 64-bit integer of the number of seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970, so after the conversion, comparison becomes trivial.